# How to get back my non-dismissable notifications?

Tags: android

My Android app show an ONGOING notification.

It worked the same from Android1 to 13.

Shameless, Google decided to make ongoing (persistent) notification to nonpersistent: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/behavior-changes-all#non-dismissable-notifications

While this might be an unfair question, but can I force this back for my application?